# Asp.Net Core PageStart.cshtml alternative?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

New to Asp.Net Core MVC I'm looking for a way to make sure users can't access a specific folder and subfolders unless a specific cookie is set. In Razor Pages I can just put a PageStart.cshtml file in the folder, that checks for the cookie, and redirects to somewhere if not.

How can I do something similar?

I think there must be some way, as checking for the cookie in every PageModel is not very DRY. :)

And yes, I'm aware of the build-in authentication/authorization, but that's not what I want.

Thanks. :)

--

```
app.Use((context, next) => {
    var requestPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
    var cookies = context.Request.Cookies;
    if (cookies["AdminId"] == null && requestPath.StartsWith("/admin", StringComparison.CurrentCulture)) {
        //await next.Invoke();
        context.Response.Redirect("/");
    }
    return next.Invoke();
});
```

Comment: `_ViewStart.cshtml` ?

Comment: @stuartd - I'm not sure that's what he's looking for.  _ViewStart will only run when rendering a view, he wants something that happens when a folders contents are displayed.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch ah I missed the folder requirement, thanks,

Comment: Check out the [Authorize] attribute and decorate your applicable methods on each controller.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2  This link will help you get started but you should find the .netcore one

Comment: Does MVC even have the same concept of "folders"?  Everything starts at the requested action.  If certain actions (or entire controllers) need to be restricted (or need to otherwise share some cross-cutting functionality) then you would generally use a method/class attribute to do that.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of _ViewStart.cshtml and that's what I'm using now. But still if you call a url (folder/file) under the _ViewStart.cshtml rootfolder, you get an error if that specific cookie is not found.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns I'd prefer not to use the Identity-thing if possible. Also, then you still need to set [AllowAnonymous] or [Authorize] in every controller, right?

Comment: View the reference source and create your own cookie-based version.  Be prepared to be hacked since cookies are 100% controlled by the caller.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest against writing your own authentication/authorization mechanism unless youre somewhat of an expert on these topics already. Is there a reason your against using Identity?

Comment: How will you access the `Folder`? Will you access the files in folder by http request or access them from controller? If you access from http request, you could implement your own middleware which could intercept every request to backend.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns why should I be prepared to be hacked? Because you can manipulate with cookies?

Comment: @GregH Mainly because I've read a lot of docs and tutorials about it and it just don't makes sense to me. Probably because I'm not yet skillful enough. The system I'm trying to build is an upgrade from an ASP Classic site, so I already have a member database with privileges and so on.

Comment: @TaoZhou Yes, I'll access the files in the folders by HTTP. Can you guide me in a direction or show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

For intercepting HTTP Request for static file, try code below before `app.UseStaticFiles();`.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    var requestPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
    var cookies = context.Request.Cookies;
    if (!requestPath.StartsWith("/Home/About"))
    {
        await next.Invoke();
    }
    else
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Forbidden");
    }
});

app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Comment: It looks like what I need. I've changed it a little to fit my needs, but still I can navigate to a "denied" file. The code is in my edited question.

Can you see what's wrong? The code is inserted before the App.UseStaticFiles()

Comment: Well, it's partly working (just like the _ViewStart.cshtml I had before): if I enter a url where the controller expects the AdminId-cookie I receive an error instead of being redirected. Otherwise I'm correctly redirected to the login-page.

Comment: @Mads Could you share more details when will it throw error?

Comment: Yes, what do you need? When I call this URL "/admin/participants/list" I get an "ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null."-error because the OnGetAsync-controller on that page expects a cookie, that is set at login. So the controller must be read before the app.Use redirects the user? The same problem I had with the _ViewStart.cshtml in my /admin folder.

Comment: @Mads Is there any demo project to reproduce your issue? It seems to be more related with your implementation.

Comment: At the moment I'm developing on a local computer, so I can't give you the URL. What else do you need to see? If necessary I can send the VS solution to you. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Mads If your issue not resolved, share us the demo solution through github.

Comment: I've uploaded the solution to GitHub: https://github.com/MSchioldan/VPV

Comment: @Mads Is there any step required to run your project? I got `The layout view '_Layout' could not be located` after launching your project.

Comment: Sorry: /admin :)

Comment: Actually I don't know if it'll work. I removed some information (connectionstring and "salt strings") from appsettings.json that I don't want exposed.